# Get week number using date in python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601, week-number, python-datetime

Date is  `datetime.date(2013, 12, 30)`

I am trying to get week number using

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2013, 12, 30).isocalendar()[1]
```

I am getting output as ,

```
1
```

Why i am not getting week number of last year , instead i am getting week number of current year?

Whats wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong so I can't answer your question directly.  You can verify these with isweeknumber.com and other sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, `2013/12/30` falls in week 1 of 2014, according to the [ISO8601 week numbering standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

The Thursday in that week is 2014/01/02.

Other ways to explain the definition, from the same linked WikiPedia article:

> - It is the first week with a majority (four or more) of its days in January (ISO weeks start on Monday)
> - Its first day is the Monday nearest to 1 January.
> - It has 4 January in it. Hence the earliest possible dates are 29 December through 4 January, the latest 4 through 10 January.
> - It has the year's first working day in it, if Saturdays, Sundays and 1 January are not working days.

If you were looking for the last week number of a given year (52 or 53, depending on the year), I'd use December 28th, which is always guaranteed to be in the last week (because January 4th is always part of the *first* week of the next year):

```
def lastweeknumber(year):
    return datetime.date(year, 12, 28).isocalendar()[1]
```

Comment: Thanks , Then how can i get last week number using this method?

Comment: @Nishant: You mean you want 52, the last full week in 2013? I'll update.

Comment: @Nishant: Sorry, my brain didn't kick in sooner, the last revision is the best one to determine the last week number of a year.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
ndate='10/1/2016'
ndate = datetime.strptime(ndate, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
print('new format:',ndate)
d=ndate.split(',')
wkno = date(int(d[0]),int(d[1]),int(d[2])).isocalendar()[1]
print(wkno)
```

manually or read a date to a string and get the week number, play around with different formats.

Comment: The question was: *"Why i am not getting week number of last year , instead i am getting week number of current year?

Whats wrong i am doing here ?"*

Comment: It's supposed to be the first week of 2014 till Jan 4th

Comment: I didn't comment your code but that your answer didn't hit the target - the code is *done*, what's wrong with *its* output?