# python get same day last year

Tags: python, datetime

how to get same day last year in python

I tried  `datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=1)` but this doesn't produce the result I'm looking.

Can anyone help. Thanks

example:

20/08/2020 (Thursday) last  year will be 22/08/2019 (Thursday)

Comment: Ignoring leap years, wouldn't it be `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)` ?

Comment: So you're really asking "how do I find the Nth day of a year"?

Comment: You need to back up 52 weeks, not 1 year.

Comment: not every year has 52 weeks! See my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want the same day of week one year ago. A year has 52 weeks

```
print(datetime.datetime.now())
2020-08-20 17:56:56.397626

print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=52))
2019-08-22 17:56:56.397626
```

Comment: Although this answer has been marked as accepted, as it works for you in most cases, you might be very nastily surprised at beginning/ending of some years, as this solution does not count with ISO 8601. Check my other answer below...

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Pranav Hosangadi here is very nice, but please note that not every year has 52 weeks! It may be also 53, if you follow the
[ISO8601 week numbering standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Number of ISO weeks in a year may be get [according to this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140371/get-week-number-using-date-in-python), resulting in you code:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now())
2020-08-20 22:57:28.061648
 
def lastweeknumberoflastyear():
    return datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now().year-1, 12, 28).isocalendar()[1]

print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=lastweeknumberoflastyear()))
2019-08-22 22:57:28.061785
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_year = now.replace(now.year - 1)
```

Note that this will not account for leap years. If you want to find a date exactly 365 days prior, you would instead do something like:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_year = now - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably do it like this, as a year is not always 365 days.

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.now()
last_year = datetime(x.year-1,x.month,x.day,x.hour,x.minute,x.second,x.microsecond)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want to look at today's date and then get the same date but last year:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
previous_year = today.year -1
today_last_year = today.replace(year = previous_year)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP wanted to know how to get the same **day of week** last year, not the same date.